# Writing minimum equation

Tags: education

How can i write minimum number of a series as an equation?

```
min(4, 2) = 2
or
min([5, 1, 8, 6]) = 1
```

Like the following one

```
∑Xi
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question exactly, but if $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 0}$ is a (bounded) sequence of real numbers, you can write $\min_{n \geq 0} a_n$ for the minimum term of the sequence.

Comment: We write absolute function like |x-y| or |-2| = 2. So i am looking for how to write minimum value of a given series or numbers in math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two arguments:

$$\min\{x,y\}=\frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}$$

For more arguments you recurse:

$$
\min\{x,y,z\}=
$$
$$
\min\{\min\{x,y\},z\}=
$$
$$
\frac{\min\{x,y\}+z-|\min\{x,y\}-z|}{2}=
$$
$$
\frac{\frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}+z-\left|\frac{x+y-|x-y|}{2}-z\right|}{2}.
$$

Comment: So it's brackets. Thank you so much